# Controlled publishing in Wordpress

Tags: publish, staging

We are currently rebuilding our corporate website and I'm looking for a way to control the publishing of pages. The flow to create or amend pages would be something like this:

1) New page is built or existing page is amended.

2) Page is promoted to a staging level where the business can review and approve layout or suggest changes.

3) Approval is received from business, page is added to a queue where it will be published at specific time.

Any advice on this appreciated, I've done a bit of digging but haven't found anything that would work the way I want it.

Regards...

Comment: you should be able to do this all with standard wordpress using status, visibility and publication time. Am I correct in assuming you want automate this process as much as possible so users don't have to remember to change a post to pending review when its updated e.t.c?

Comment: Have you looked at [Revisionary](https://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/)?

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll take a look at that plugin. @MarkDavidson Thanks Mark, yes an automated approach would be preferred.